# Can't add object to another object with map

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I've ran into a problem I've never seen before in javascript. Here's the essence of what I am doing

```
var doStuff = function(stuff, otherstuff){
   return _.map(stuff, function(s){

     // Thing needed is a fairly big object 
     var thingNeeded = _.find(otherstuff, function(os){
       return os.whatineed;
     });

     var new_thing = _.clone(s);
     new_thing.new_field = thingNeeded;
     return new_thing;
   });
};
```

But this returns a list that is the original `stuff` list! It even occurs if I do this variation

```
var doStuff = function(stuff, otherstuff){
   return _.map(stuff, function(s){

     // Thing needed is a fairly big object 
     var thingNeeded = _.find(otherstuff, function(os){
       return os.whatineed;
     });


     s.new_field = thingNeeded;
     return s;
   });
};
```

or

```
var doStuff = function(stuff, otherstuff){
   return _.map(stuff, function(s){

     // Thing needed is a fairly big object 
     var thingNeeded = _.find(otherstuff, function(os){
       return os.whatineed;
     });


     s['new_field'] = thingNeeded;
     return s;
   });
};
```

Or variations using `_.extend()` and `_.create()`. It also doesn't work with the map in the array prototype.

I have no idea what I may be doing wrong here. Its completely ignoring me adding the field. Can anyone help?

*EDIT:* for the record

```
[{thing: 1}, {thing: 2}].map(function(t){
  t.welp = 'welp';
});
```

will return `[{thing: 1, welp: 'welp'}, {thing: 2, welp: 'welp'}]` as expected. So its somewhere inside the map.

*EDIT AGAIN:*

```
var doStuff = function(stuff, otherstuff){
   return _.map(stuff, function(s){

     // Thing needed is a fairly big object 
     var thingNeeded = _.find(otherstuff, function(os){
       return os.whatineed;
     });

     var new_thing = _.clone(s);
     new_thing.new_field = thingNeeded;
     console.log('stuff:', new_thing.new_field);
     return new_thing;
   });
};
```

The console.log will return the value we'd expect (thingNeeded).

Thank you!

Comment: Try clone thing needed as well?

Comment: In the last two cases, you're passing 'os' to the 'find' callback but then using'otherstuff' inside there.  In the first case, if '.whatineed' doesn't exist on 'otherstuff', then you'll get exactly what you're seeing.

Comment: @caasjj thanks for pointing out the typo.

Comment: @korven cloning that doesn't fix anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using stuff within your map iterator when you should be using the currently iterated object 's'.

Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rzkvne23/

```
var doStuff = function(stuff, otherstuff){
   return _.map(stuff, function(s){

     var thingNeeded = _.find(otherstuff, function(os){
       return os.whatineed === 2;
     });

     var new_thing = _.clone(s);
     new_thing.new_field = thingNeeded;
     console.log('stuff:', new_thing.new_field);
     return new_thing;
   });
};

var a = [{},{},{}];
var b = [{whatineed: 1},{whatineed:2},{whatineed:3}];

console.dir(doStuff(a,b));
```

Comment: this will never be solved. You found another typo. I'm sorry. In the real code I'm cloning s similar to the other examples where I'm using s. I about to just give up on this and do something else. I hate javascript for exactly this reason.